# different result with scipy integrate.tplquad

Tags: python, scipy, wolfram-mathematica

With Matematica this integral gives me 3.    [wolfram alpha](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/b076ab70-cc39-4e74-bb40-df90808c6ad4#sidebar=compute/%22mathematica%22)
With  integrate.tplquad I get -3.
This is Matematica code.

```
Integrate[1-x, {(0,2),(0,3-1.5*x),(0,6-3*x -2*y)}]
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong with ntegrate.tplquad

```
f = lambda x,y,z: 1-x   

x1, x2 = 0,2

y1, y2 = lambda x : 0 , lambda x:3-1.5*x

z1, z2  = lambda x,y:0, lambda x,y: 6 -3*x -2*y

print(integrate.tplquad(f,x1,x2, y1, y2, z1, z2)[0])
-3.0
```

Comment: @kabanus, I will update with the code. But there is is link to wolfram on the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-check the [`tplquad` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html); you'll see that the signature of the function `f` is `f(z, y, x)`.  So it looks like your integrand should be:

```
   f = lambda x, y, z: 1 - z
```

Comment: I actually thought it more natural to change the signature rather than the function. Weird how these things are.

Comment: This one is really counter intuitive. Thank you.